# Desactivar desplazamiento tactil en moviles con Glider.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Tengo un slider con glider.js, funciona todo bien pero quiero desactivar que se pueda pasar de slide con el táctil en la versión móvil, que solo se pueda pasar con los botones de siguiente y anterior, no he podio encontrar si es posible en la documentación oficial, así es como creo el carrusel

```
new Glider(document.querySelector('.carousel__list'), {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        dots: '.carousel__indicators',
        draggable: false,
        arrows: {
        prev: '.carousel__prev',
        next: '.carousel__next'
            },
 });
```

Comment: Lamento la confusión con la respuesta; sin embargo, creo que no hay opción para desactivar el desplazamiento, porque en [la documentación](https://nickpiscitelli.github.io/Glider.js/) mencionan como ventaja: _"Your mobile users will thank you! (or anyone with a touch device really)"_ y, al final, _"still allowing other default scrolling methods"_. Básicamente, es amigable con dispositivos táctiles. La opción `draggable` solo es para arrastrar con clic del mouse.